# Page not found: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml/

Tags: django, sitemap

Here are the codes to create the sitemap for one of my app 'blog' in my site: (using Django 2.0)

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS += [
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
] 
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from blog.sitemaps import PostSiteMap

sitemaps = {'posts': PostSiteMap}

urlpatterns += [
path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, 
name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
]
```

sitempas.py (under 'blog' app directory)

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from .models import Post


class PostSiteMap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'weekly'
    priority = 0.5

def items(self):
    return Post.published.all()

def lastmod(self, obj):
    return obj.publish
```

The sitemap.xml doesn't appear: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml/
[image]

[image]

There is the url (the eighth) matching my inputted one. Why it says 'not match'?

Comment: You have a trailing slash in the URL you are going to, but not in your pattern. Usually for a path like that you wouldn't have one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added the trialling slash in the pattern (see the updated image in above post), but the the same problem still exists.

Comment: But now you're going to just /sitemap/.

Comment: @DanielRoseman "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap/" not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is good, your environment is what is **wrong** (maybe you are using the default Django site, that is www.example.com). Change it to a local environment (the typical `127.0.0.1:8000`).

To do this in Django you need to do the following:

1. Check if you are running the local server in your command prompt, if is not, type `python manage.py runserver`.
2. go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/site/`
3. Change the default site (typically the default in Django is `example.com`) to `127.0.0.1:8000`. This needs to be done in the **domain and display name** (while you aren't in a production environment).
4. Press `F5` in your local web page in your browser.
5. go to your sitemap page (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml`)
6. And voilà! there is your sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

Write full /sitemap.xml like this and try
Enter this url and load page
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml/

Comment: No. It doesn't work (I have added the error output in the post now.

Comment: Try sitemaps/ and where is.the template sitemap.xml

Comment: I don't get why using sitemaps/ , but I try it as well which doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you created admin panel.for site??

Comment: If in installed apps you added django.contrib.sites in INSTALLED_APP then  run python manage.py migrate

Comment: Now it works after I added 127.0.0.1:8000 in admin panel for site. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162687/discussion-between-amy-and-humza-jalal).

Answer (score 1):

The error is

> Site matching query does not exist

which means that you have to setup and configure [Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites).

To enable the sites framework, follow these steps:

1. Add 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
2. Define a SITE_ID setting:

   SITE_ID = 1
3. Run migrate.

For more information check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites).

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding '127.0.0.1:8000' in admin panel for sites.